# How to detect if file isn't found

Tags: vb.net

I'm a bit new to VB.NET. I was wondering if there was a way to detect if a file being open doesn't exist, then something will happen. Is this possible and is it possible using the "If" statement?

Comment: please search on the web before asking... this is what you may find. https://www.google.fr/search?q=vb.net+file+exists&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:fr:official&client=firefox-beta

Comment: Yes its possible, eg http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx however there is a school of thought that suggest this is pointless as other things can modify the file system in between checking and opening, so use try catch instead.

Comment: Make that a university of thought.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `file.exists(filename)` to check before you open it, or a try-catch block:

```
If not System.IO.File.Exists(filename) Then
  ' file does not exist
  end if
```

or

```
Try
  open ...
Catch ex As Exception
  MsgBox(ex.Message)  ' not-found error handling goes here
End Try
```

You can add `imports system.io` at the top of your file to use `File.Exists` instead of `System.IO.File.Exists`.

Comment: For catch block I would recommend using `FileNotFoundException`, rather than generic `Exception`.

Comment: Wow! I didn't even know about that, after umpteen years. Thanks!